# SQL Server - Find e-mail address in a string

Tags: sql-server, email

I am trying to retrieve a part of comments field in our database, that contains just the e-mail address. So for example, Comment might look like this:

```
Type of Count: Itemised  EPOS: CBE    Email Reports to: user@gmail.com  
CC user@domain.ie  Name of Email recipient: Xxxxx  
Store Contact: Person PhoneNumber    Wet stock: No  Deli: Yes  Packaging: Yes    Additional Requirements:   Payment Terms: On the day.    
Supervisor Feedback  Count Issues or concerns: No  Unusual Storage Areas: No  Payment received: Yes  Payment sent to Office: 
Posted on Monday 29th June 2015    Downtime due to IT issues: None  Details:
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT  st.Comments,        
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('@',st.Comments) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE SUBSTRING(st.Comments,beginningOfEmail,endOfEmail-beginningOfEmail)
    END email , sc.CustomerName1
FROM tblStockTakes st
INNER JOIN tblCustomers sc ON st.CustomerId = sc.CustomerId
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ',st.Comments + 'Reports to:     ',CHARINDEX('@',st.Comments))) AS A(endOfEmail)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEN(st.Comments)/2 - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE('EPOS: ' +     st.Comments),CHARINDEX('@',REVERSE(' ' + st.Comments))) + 2) AS     B(beginningOfEmail)
WHERE st.StockTakeDate BETWEEN '2015-06-27 06:00:00.000' AND '2015-10-28 06:00:00.000'
```

Which returns the following:

```
Type of Count: Itemised  EPOS: CBE    Email Reports to: user@gmail.com  CC
```

What should I change in the query to remove the front part, and just start with Email Reports To: xxx@gmail.com?

Thanks for any advise!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract email address from string using tsql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596780/extract-email-address-from-string-using-tsql)

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to format your string which might need a little bit of adjustment. I put comments for `beginningOfEmail` and `endOfEmail`, in case you want to keep your strategy of creating the values in a `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SUBSTRING(st.Comments
,PATINDEX('%Email Reports to: %',st.Comments) --beginningOfEmail
,PATINDEX('%.com CC%',st.Comments)-PATINDEX('%Email Reports to: %',st.Comments)+4) --endOfEmail
```