# Return text surrounding specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a free-form text field in a table that contains email addresses. Problem is there is lots of other info in this field, before and after the email address.
Edit: Here's an example of what the field might look like:

```
Address: 123 Anystreet. Customer requires xyz. Email: person@example.com Other random info...
```

I'm thinking the best way to try and extract just the email addresses is to have SQL search for the @ character, and retrieve all surrounding text until a space is reached. Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure the email is always surrounded by spaces?

Comment: There are maximum length to parts of an email address too (I don't remember them exactly, an ancient standard somewhere RFC...) but could your data have multiple email addresses separated by comma or semi-colon?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Reasonably sure. Let's assume that yes, that is always the case. See example I added to question.

Comment: @Used_By_Already no unfortunately not. The data is a mess, completely inconsistent. See example above.

Comment: have you tried any of the approaches from this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596780/extract-email-address-from-string-using-tsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an answer [at former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596780/extract-email-address-from-string-using-tsql) (Apr 13 '15 at 2:44 by Stephan)
see this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3466/2)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([BigString] varchar(100))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([BigString])
VALUES
    ('Address: 123 Anystreet. Customer requires xyz. Email: person@example.com Other random info...'),
    ('blah MyEmailAddress@domain.org'),
    ('blah MyEmailAddress@domain.org blah blah'),
    ('MyEmailAddress@domain.org blah'),
    ('no email')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select BigString, c3.email
from (
    select BigString
    from Table1
    where CHARINDEX('@',BigString) > 0
    ) t
cross apply (select charindex('@',BigString)) c1 (atpos)
cross apply (select charindex(' ',BigString + ' ',c1.atpos), reverse(substring(BigString,1,c1.atpos))
            ) c2 (endOfEmail,RevString)  
cross apply (select RTRIM(Reverse(left(RevString,charindex(' ',RevString+' ')-1))
                  + substring(BigString,c1.atpos+1,endOfEmail-c1.atpos))
            ) c3 (email)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3466/2/0)**:

```
|                                                                                     BigString |                     email |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------------------------|
| Address: 123 Anystreet. Customer requires xyz. Email: person@example.com Other random info... |        person@example.com |
|                                                                blah MyEmailAddress@domain.org | MyEmailAddress@domain.org |
|                                                      blah MyEmailAddress@domain.org blah blah | MyEmailAddress@domain.org |
|                                                                MyEmailAddress@domain.org blah | MyEmailAddress@domain.org |
```

Comment: I searched before asking but of course could not find anything. My google-fu must be rusty...thanks for this, I will try it out.

Comment: think my google-fu was along the lines of "extract email from long string" but way too much rubbish returned :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it

```
SELECT Email = Reverse(Substring(Reverse(string), revpos+1, Charindex(' ', Reverse(string), revpos)-revpos))
               + Substring(string, pos, Charindex(' ', string, pos)-pos)
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply(VALUES (Charindex('@', string)))tc(pos)
       CROSS apply(VALUES (Charindex('@', Reverse(string))))tc1(revpos)
```

Note :

This assumes two things

1. There is always only one `@` present
2. `Email` is always surrounded by space

### [Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/RAWQME58942)

Comment: using a larger set of sample data, this code needs `+ ' '`  when charindex is used to avoid invalid length errors see http://rextester.com/JTEOO10362